# Apply animation on img inside grid item when hover on grid item

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I created a grid item that has 5 elements in it and it looks as follows:

[image]

I had like to add animation once the mouse is hovering the grid-item but I want it to animate only the `grid-img`. What I mean is that if the user hovering at the any place on the grid item, I want it to make animation only on the `grid-img`.

I use the following CSS for this:

```
.grid-item {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border: 3px solid rgba(255, 254, 5, 0.4);
  border-radius: 10px;
  column-gap: 10px;
  color: rgba(255, 254, 5, 0.4);
  display: grid;
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-row-start: 8;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.grid-name {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
}

.grid-image {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 4;
}

.grid-level {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  justify-self: left;
}

.grid-rank {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  justify-self: left;
}

.grid-xp {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  justify-self: left;
}

.grid-style:hover {
  animation: rotation 4s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(359deg);
  }
}
```

and in my HTML:

```
<div class="grid-item grid-style">
    <div class="grid-name">
        <p class="skill">A</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-image">
        <img src="/static/icons/A.png">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-rank">
        <p class="small">Current rank: 200000000</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-level">
        <p class="small">Current level:100</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-xp">
        <p class="small">Current XP: 200000000</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

what this code does right now is that the whole grid-item rotating when I hover it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are rotating the wole element (.grid-style).

To rotate just its img child you can first select the .grid-style with pseudo class hover then the child:

```
.grid-style:hover .grid-image {
  animation: rotation 4s infinite linear;
}
```

```css
.grid-item {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border: 3px solid rgba(255, 254, 5, 0.4);
  border-radius: 10px;
  column-gap: 10px;
  color: rgba(255, 254, 5, 0.4);
  display: grid;
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-row-start: 8;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.grid-name {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
}

.grid-image {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 4;
}

.grid-level {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  justify-self: left;
}

.grid-rank {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  justify-self: left;
}

.grid-xp {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  justify-self: left;
}

.grid-style:hover .grid-image {
  animation: rotation 4s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-item grid-style">
  <div class="grid-name">
    <p class="skill">A</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-image">
    <img src="/static/icons/A.png">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-rank">
    <p class="small">Current rank: 200000000</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-level">
    <p class="small">Current level:100</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-xp">
    <p class="small">Current XP: 200000000</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining!

Answer (score 0):

Just use selector in the way mentioned below on the animation property.

```
.grid-style:hover .grid-image {
  animation: rotation 4s infinite linear;
}
```